# React Native List View Does not Render

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

My code:

```js
const tabscreen = (screen, path, label, src) => {
  return {
    screen, path,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: label,
      tabBarIcon: ({
                     tintColor,
                     focused = true
                   }) => (<TabIcon src={src} active={focused}/>),
    }
  };
};




const MainTab = TabNavigator({
  Home: tabscreen(HomeScreen, '/home', 'home', 'home'),
  Chat: tabscreen(ChatScreen, '/chat', 'chat', 'chat'),
  Find: tabscreen(FindScreen, '/find', 'find', 'find'),
  Profile: tabscreen(ProfileScreen, '/profile', 'find', 'profile')
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  swipeEnabled: false,
  animationEnabled: false,
  lazy: false,
  //...other configs
  tabBarOptions: {
    // tint color is passed to text and icons (if enabled) on the tab bar
    activeTintColor: '#1BBC9B',
    inactiveTintColor: '#9B9B9B',
    showIcon: true,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#F4F4F4',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      height: 49
    },
    labelStyle: {
      marginTop: 0,
      marginLeft: 0,
      marginRight: 0,
      marginBottom: 1.5
    }
  }
});


 const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainTab ,
    path: '/',
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      headerVisible: false,
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
  },


}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
      gesturesEnabled: true,
      headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerBackTitle: null,
  }
});
```

[image]

This demo uses redux to control state. 
 In the `FindScreen`, I use the `List view` to render a list. The problem is when I click the `Find` tab. The `List view` does not render. **I have to first swipe the screen, then the `List view` show.**

[image]

I used `connect` of `redux-react` to map the dispatch to `FindScreen` component. I request the data source of the `List view` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if( nextProps.doctorList !== this.props.doctorList){
      debugger;
      this.setState({
        isRefreshing: false,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.doctorList),
      })
    }
}
```

As the code above, I set the debugger in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook. The breakpoint stops at the line of the debugger. Now, I know I request the data from the backend well.

Do you know the reason of the `List view` does not render?
 What can I do to show the `List view` in the first render?

I know one way of solving this problem is change `lazy: false,` to  `lazy: true`. Due to the `lazy: false` is written by my leader, so I had better not change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `removeClippedSubviews={false}` to your ListView.

You can refer to https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1279 for the fix.
Please note that this is not an ideal fix because this is disabling a performance optimization.

You can read about the performance optimization here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#removeclippedsubviews